# Is there any tool to access the graphical interface of Ubuntu EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on AWS services and I can easily access Windows instances using "Remote Desktop Tools" but in order to access the Ubuntu instance, I usually use Terminal.

Is there any way to graphically access the Ubuntu instance?

Comment: I think this is what you are lookging for http://superuser.com/questions/249045/x11-forwarding-from-amazon-ec2-ami

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in a comment, [X11 forwarding from Amazon EC2 AMI](https://superuser.com/questions/249045/x11-forwarding-from-amazon-ec2-ami) is part of the solution.  To get multiple programs working together (as a *desktop*), you might also want to investigate VNC:

- [Administer Ubuntu Server Trusty Tahr 14.04LTS using VNC](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html)
- [How do I install a VNC server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server)
- [Using VNC to Operate a Desktop on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/using-vnc-to-operate-a-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [How To Install VNC Server On Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04)

(You would use X forwarding with VNC, of course)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Open a ec2 Ubuntu terminal using a PuTTY. Refer for more detail how to connect your Linux instance from Windows using PuTTY https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Step 2: Run the following commands on PuTTY Ubuntu terminal step by step

```
sudo apt update
```

Install xrdp to allow RDP connections:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt install xrdp
```

Set a password for the ubuntu user:

```
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

Step 3:

```
Go to AWS console
Click on instance(running)
Select your running Ubuntu instance
Go to Security
Click on Security Groups
Click on Edit inbound rules
In type drop down select RDP
It by default select port 3389
In Source add 0.0.0.0/0 IP
Click on Save rules
```

Step 4:

```
Open Remote Desktop Connection on windows machine
Enter Computer: Public IP of ubuntu ec2 and add username:your_user_name
click on connect will open up GUI version of Ubuntu (linux), It ask for password please enter the set password.
```